# Query where one field includes the text string in another field

Tags: query, string

I am trying to query mailing address records that match physical address records, but the two fields sometimes have data in a different format.  For example, the property's mailing address may be shown as '123 NW Elm Street', while the physical address may be shown as '123 Elm St'.  Even if I can just query whether the address contains the same street name that would help me if I knew if 'Elm' was anywhere in the address.  There is a field with just street name, with no number or prefix or suffix.

I am trying to do a definition query to select nearly matching records with wildcards with something like this:

```
"StreetAddress" LIKE "%StreetName%"
```

I have tried numerous variations with no luck, including '%'+"STreetName"+'%' etc.

Is there a "FIELD_A" INCLUDES "FIELD_B" query or a "FIELD_A" CONTAINS "FIELD_B" command?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Please also **edit the question** to specify the data source format, since the functions available are defined by the software in use and the capabilities of the data store.

Answer (score 2):

You need a nested query.

```
StreetAddress IN (SELECT StreetName FROM <Whatever you layer is named>)
```

e.g. `StreetAddress IN (SELECT StreetName FROM House_Addresses)` - House_Addresses is the layer name in this example.

Also, if you have not heard of Fuzzy tables/relationships you should look into them.  They may provide a solution.

Here's the tool for excell:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Python:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy

Video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3v-qxcjZbyo

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using ArcGIS, you can make the comparison in field calculator (Python parser), and select on that:

```
1 if !StreetName! in !StreetAddress! else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @phloem suggests, you can use python's [difflib module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) with `get_close_matches` or `SequenceMatcher.ratio` methods. The former gives you the best matching entries within a set/iterable, say whole of a column, while the latter gives you a score by comparing inputted pair, i.e., values in two columns of a row. For example:

`difflib.get_close_matches('123 NW Elm Street', ['123 Elm St'],1,0.7)[0]` will give you `'123 Elm St'`, whereas

`int(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,  '123 NW Elm Street', '123 Elm St').ratio()*100)` will compare source with target and yield a matching score, `74`.